# Programmatically sending bytes to ffmpeg via STDIN to create still image file

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, stdin

I am attempting to use vb.net code to send individual pixel information as bytes to ffmpeg with the purpose of saving a still DPX image file. I have already successfully read DPX files and output them via STDOUT into vb.net code.

There seem to be many examples out there of piping movie files but there are also discrepancies, such as some people using image2pipe and others using rawvideo. I am uncertain when to use one over the other. The various methods I've tried result in ffmpeg returned errors such as "Packet too small for DPX header" or "Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input". As I understand it, I am not providing a header, only the raw individual pixel RGBRGBRGB.... values as a byte array.

The arguments sent to ffmpeg via command line are:

-f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -s 16x16 -bits_per_raw_sample 8 -c:v dpx -i - \MyPath\MyFilename.dpx

My vb.net code is as follows:

```
Dim P As New Process
P.StartInfo.FileName = m_FFMPEGExecutable_PathFile
P.StartInfo.Arguments = (see above arguments)
P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
P.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
P.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
p.Start


'Test image: A single red, green, blue, black and white pixel followed by all black

Dim Tiny((16 * 16) - 1) As Byte

Tiny(0) = 255
Tiny(1) = 0
Tiny(2) = 0

Tiny(3) = 0
Tiny(4) = 255
Tiny(5) = 0

Tiny(6) = 0
Tiny(7) = 0
Tiny(8) = 255

For i As byte = 9 To ((16x16)-1)
   Tiny(i) = 255
Next

'Send the rgb byte array to ffmpeg:
P.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(Tiny, 0, Tiny.Length)
P.StandardInput.Flush()
P.StandardInput.Close()
```

I have tried many variations on the above ffmpeg arguments but cannot seem to avoid these errors. Any suggestions would be appreciated, including information on when to use image2pipe vs. rawvideo.

Comment: Since you're sending a raw bitstream, use rawvideo. Remove `-c:v dpx`

Comment: Can you explain the difference between a raw bitstream and image2pipe? As I understand it, both are a stream of r,g,b, bytes?

Comment: A raw bitstream doesn't have any metadata. image2pipe can be used to send container formats like JPEGs, PNGs..etc

Comment: Gyan, I did as you suggested (used rawvideo instead of image2pipe, and removed '-c:v dpx' from the arguments. This resulted in slightly different errors...............................pipe:: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0000025ebf58e0c0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 256 < expected frame_size 768
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument

Comment: For a 16x16 image with format rgb24, you are expected to send 16x16x3 bytes. The first byte in every triplet is R, then G then B. You appear to sending only 256 bytes.

Comment: Gyan-Using the incorrect number of bytes on my part was a silly mistake on my part. Correcting that allows your original suggestion of using -rawvideo to solve the problem. Thank you.